# UIPopoverPresentationController being cut on iPad iOS 10

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode8, ios10

Im trying to show a list inside a popover controller using 
UIAlertController. Works well on iOS 8, 9. On iOS 10 ipad it gets cut. Although I am adding actions and verified it is being added but the popover gets cut. Please suggest . Below is my code -

```
UIAlertController * view=   [UIAlertController
                                 alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                 message:nil
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    if(IS_IPAD) {

            UIPopoverPresentationController *popPresenter = [view
                                                                                                             popoverPresentationController];
            [view setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];
            [view setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
                popPresenter.sourceView = self.view;
                popPresenter.sourceRect = CGRectMake(70, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

        popPresenter.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;
    }


    // Add Cacel Action
    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"إلغاء", @"'Cancel' title for button")
                                                          style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
        [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];

    [view addAction:cancelAction];
    [self.liveFeed.filter.filtersItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(DPFilteritem *item, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if (![item.filterName isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && item.filterName.length > 0) {
            UIAlertAction* alertAction = [UIAlertAction
                                          actionWithTitle:item.filterName
                                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                          {
                                              //Do some thing here
                                              NSUInteger index = [[view actions]indexOfObject:action];

                                              [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                              [self didSelectAlertItemAtIndex:index];
                                          }];
            [view addAction:alertAction];
        }

    }];

    view.view.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
        [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:^{
                //fix for iOS 9 - known issue in iOS9. You need to set tint color in completion handler.
            view.view.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }];
    });
```

iOS 10 - ipad - 
[image]

iOS 9 - ipad -
[image]

Comment: hello. same issue with you. Finding way, did you solve it?

Comment: @kemdo not yet. still the same.

Comment: hello. i found the problem is "setTintColor" in ios 10 notwork with UIPopoverPresentationController, remove this line then it show normally. Wish you have nice day

Comment: Awesome! This worked. You made my day.[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:^{
    //fix for iOS 9 - known issue in iOS9. You need to set tint color in completion handler.
    
   [view.view setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
  }];

Comment: thanks - this was a great help. Either kemdo or Uday should open a proper StackOverflow Answer for this question.